# Netzke Grid rows from the result of a DB query

Tags: netzke

I need to create an interface which contains a **Form** and an empty **Grid**. When I select the values in the **Form** and submits a query needs to created using 3 DB tables and the result of the query should be populated in the grid.

Note:- All the form fields are dependent combo boxes.

Any Idea?

Thanks.

**Update1:-**

Three models A, B, C

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :B
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :A
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :A
end
```

In table C, I have three columns "left (integer), right(integer) and version(string, eg:- 33.77.198.1)".
In table B, I have a column named "original (integer)".

Now my form should be

1) combo box  - A - field "name"  -  Label Name

2) combo box - C - field  "version" - Label Version 1

3) combo box - C - field  "version" - Label Version 2

Now when select all these 3 values an Submit then a query should be created and the results should displayed in my Grid.

Query: -

```
    SELECT a.name,c.version,
           b.name, b.original
    FROM B b 
    inner join C c on c.a_id = b.a_id
    inner join A a on a.id = b.a_id
    where b.a_id = 31   
    and b.original between 
                        ( select left from c where version = "347.0.112.227")
                        and
                        ( select right from c where version = "347.0.112.529")
```

Here 31 - selected value  from combo box A
347.0.112.227 - selected value  from combo box B
347.0.112.529 - selected value  from combo box C

Comment: Could you please explain your data model in more details? Like, which tables are how are they related? What would be the content of combos?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Please check the updated question